# Safely increase the stack size to a big amount in Mac

Tags: memory

I'm using Mac 11.6 with memory 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3.

I have coded a program in OCaml whose compilation caused `Fatal error: exception Stack overflow`, I thus wanted to raise the stack size of preprocessor.

Here is the result of `$ ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 2560
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2784
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

I tried `$ ulimit -s unlimited`, it returned `-bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted`.

I tried `ulimit -s 65533`, it did increase the stack size to `65533`, but the compilation still returned `Fatal error: exception Stack overflow`.

Does anyone know how to safely increase the stack size to an amount as big as possible?

Comment: Are you sure `OCaml` doesn’t have it’s own internal limit? Alternately, have you checked to see how high the stack is climbing before it errors (possibly with and without setting ulimit)? You can probably do the latter with a simple print statement.

Comment: If my experience with other languages is anything like yours with OCaml, then **a stack overflow is almost always caused by a programming error** (infinite recursion). (That would tie in with your program failing even after you've increased the stack size.) And even if not, you're better off tweaking your program so it can in on a standard stack (e.g. by converting recursion to iteration).

Comment: You can activate performance mode which may help. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202528